# Powershell w32tm command error: Getting AD DC list for default domain...GetDcList failed with error code: 0x80070774

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script to return the w32tm status of a host, I run this-

```
$serverlist = @(w32tm /monitor | Where-Object{$_.StartsWith("    NTP:") -and !$_.StartsWith("    NTP: error")})
```

To get a list of all the NTP sources and their time offsets

When I run it as a domain account it works fine, but when I run it as the Local System Account i get this error-

> Getting AD DC list for default domain...GetDcList failed with error
>   code: 0x80070774. Exiting with error 0x80070774

Is there any way I can get around this? I don't want to change the user account that the script runs under for other reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**w32time /monitor**  gets the information from the Domain Controller (PDC).

For the same reason, it needs the domain admin credentials to fetch it.

But if you wish to get the information locally, then you should use:

```
w32tm /query /configuration
```

Hope you can understand the difference.